# CASE in ORDER BY Clause: Why doesn't it work?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-order-by, case

After looking at some example of this simple query online, I'm at a loss as to why it doesn't work.

I'm using SQL Server 2012.

```
USE TSQL2012
SELECT
    orderid, shippeddate
FROM 
    Sales.Orders
WHERE
    custid = 20
ORDER BY
    CASE
        WHEN shippeddate IS NULL
            THEN shippeddate DESC
        WHEN shippeddate IS NOT NULL
            THEN shippeddate ASC
    END
```

When running this I get this error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DESC'.

Comment: Can you, at least, link me to where I can find the answer? I'm not sure how I can look for it, since I've tried it already.

Comment: Remove DESC and ASC from the THEN statement.  You can add a single DESC /ASC value after the END

Comment: @DarylWenman-Bateson: shoot. If nothing else, that was the main part I needed to have.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve Sage?

Comment: You have to create derivate table or view with ranking function (order one desc, one asc) and order this dataset.

Comment: @DarylWenman-Bateson: Well, that query was supposed to return a set with two NULL entries at the top of the list, and the challenge was, with what I knew at the time, to get the list to sort with the NULLs at the bottom. The hint was to use a CASE / WHEN structure to do it. I thought that, maybe, if I can switch the order of the sort conditionally, that would work. It's not a good solution, but I couldn't think of anything else. And then this happened. Now I'm not sure what else to try.

Comment: my suggestion - start a new question detailing the minimum amount of data you can (i.e. define the 2 columns and 3 rows of data?).  Then state what you've tried from a sql perspective and what doesn't work.  I suspect that we can get you where you want to get to, but one would need the actual detail to be able to create an answer that makes any sense

Comment: Try this: `SELECT orderid, shippeddate FROM Sales.Orders WHERE custid = 20 ORDER BY CASE WHEN shippeddate IS NULL THEN 2 ELSE 1 END, shippeddate`